# How to get date picker date in to text field?

Tags: java, sql, date, datepicker

```
Date Date1 = jXDatePicker1.getDate();
datestartField.setText(Date1);
```

Hint: `String` cannot be converted to date.

Comment: I wanted to convert date to string,i found this 
String Date=Date1.toString();
its allright.
Thank you!

Comment: JavaFX's DatePicker doesn't have a `getDate()` method

Comment: @YassinHajaj `jXDatePicker1` would suggest SwingX's JXDatePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date can not assign to textfield as it is object .You can convert it in String using SimpledateFormat

```
    Date Date1 = jXDatePicker1.getDate();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a",
                                Locale.US); 
   datestartField.setText(df.format(date1));
```

Hope so it will help you..

Comment: Or `DateFormat#getDateTime` instance and just use the locale date format

Comment: Im getting this error when im tryng to run my application
Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.Date
Anyone please tell me how to solve this?